# Can I use "any" with singular noun in formal English?

Tags: word-choice, determiners, uncountable-nouns

As far I as I remember, "any" and "some" are used with plural nouns or uncountable ones. I know about exceptions for "some" (Wow, some car).
But can I say the following and be grammatical:

> Is there any other problem?

or should be better this:

> Is there another problem?

Comment: If you are wondering about the grammaticality of such basic sentences, I wonder if you're a native speaker of English. If not, and that is the root of your uncertainty, you might want to ask questions on the site for [ell.SE]. (Please don't misinterpret my intent; you're welcome to participate actively in both communities.)

Comment: @J.R. Oh no, I am not a native speaker :) I do not think Language learners would be better place as I know the rules quite well but I am rathed interested in exceptions and usage which is not mentioned in textbooks ;)

Comment: You might consider rephrasing your question as such: **Is there a problem? vs Is there any problem?** Which one is more "formal"? Are they both grammatically correct?

Comment: @Mari-LouA The thing is that by "another" I want to emphasize that e.g. one problem is solved but - are there any other problems? I am unsure whether I can use sentences I mentioned.

Comment: I see, well the second sentence sounds perfectly fine to me. Problem is a singular noun and the auxiliary verb is in agreement. The first example is perhaps more colloquial, but perhaps considered to be ungrammatical by some.

Comment: They're both fine but they don't mean the same thing. _Is there another problem?_ invites the assumption that there has already been at least one problem. In other words, there may be a problem, and the speaker wants to know about it; this is not a rhetorical question.

Comment: _Is there any other problem?_ is a perfunctory cue, and carries no assumption that there have been any problems that haven't been solved. This is a rhetorical question, and is usually a way of closing a phone help conversation. The desired answer is "No, thank you."

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think my "problem" is how *other* and *another* should be used in these cases. Given the choice I would instinctively say: Are there any *other* problems? Because I might be anticipating that there is more than one. The question still allows a "no" response but it is also a way of saying; *Tell me now otherwise stop bothering me". I agree that limiting the question to the singular, "Is there any other problem?" could imply: I don't really want to know or care if there is one.

Comment: @Theresa: I would probably word it something along the lines of, "Are there any other problems?" so as not to presume there wouldn't be **more than one** additional problem. As for which site is more appropriate for a certain question, you might want to read [this](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/3722/what-is-the-difference-between-elu-and-ell/3723#3723).

Answer (score 1):

Yes.

- any person
- any house
- any child

are all valid.

By the way, your title would be more idiomatic if you said "Can I use any with [a|any] singularnoun in formal English?" `Any` in this case would connote a broader application ("Any singular noun at all?") than `a` ("Are there some singular nouns I can use it with?").

I concur with @Mari-Lou A that "Is there any other problem?" sounds non-idiomatic. More usual alternatives might be:

- "Is there anything else I can help you with?"
- "Have I satisfactorily answered your query?"